# Artifacts in WMP after speed-up and fps change

Tags: ffmpeg, powerpoint, mp4, frame-rate, visual-artifacts

Trying to convert a 1 hour video with 0.02 fps, to a very short one (100 times speed-up) with somethinglike 10 fps to include in a powerpoint presentation.

I did this :

```
ffmpeg - input.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=0.01*PTS" -r 10 output.mp4
```

Works great, play nicely with VLC or SMPlayer (which I believe use ffmpeg libraries for decoding). But if played with Windows Media Player, or inserted in a powerpoint presentation, this gives a lot of artifacts...the video is almost not watchable.

Is there a way to make this watchable in powerpoint (i'm guessing the problem lies down with the video renderer used in powerpoint...)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after i figured it out:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "setpts=0.01*PTS,fps=fps=1:round=near" -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -an out.mp4
```

This command will speed-up my input video 100 times, change fps from the 0.2 fps to 1fps.

I figured that specifying the profile for x264 encoder fixed my issues with windowsmedia player and powerpoint.

Apllies on Win 7, Windows MediaPlayer 12, PowerPoint 2013